# How and why Liquid helium climbs the walls of the container it is kept in?

Tags: superconductivity, superfluidity

Liquid helium (He-II) shows a strange phenomenon, where it flows on its own, forming films across the surfaces of the container it is kept in. How and why this happens and how is it possible?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

After doing a quick research, on physics.stackexchange is no answer to your question. So I share my own thoughts with you.

At very low temperatures the energy exchange between the atoms respectively molecules in the helium is reduced to a minimum and the chaotic movement of the particles is negligibly low.

Electrons and protons are not only charged particles, they are also tiny magnets. Under the influence of an external field one is able to align these magnetic dipoles and to produce permanent magnets. Near zero Kelvin one don’t need an external field, the atoms start the alignment without an external field (and more than this, under some circumstances external fields could destroy the superconductivity).
Physics describe the interaction of these ultra-cold atoms by the coherence of their wave functions.

Having a fluid with the properties of a permanent magnet, the climbing of walls could be explained with the influence of the magnetic field of this liquid with the wall and the materials behind the wall. in the same way, a permanent magnet magnetize the things nearby it, in the same way the Helium in its magnetic liquid form influences the magnetic property of the glas. Magnets attract each over and the liquid starts climbing the wall.

Hope to see here another explanation or at least a discussion around alternative explanations.

Answer (score 1):

There's some explanation in [this article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/superfluid-can-climb-walls/), but it doesn't give much of a feel for why "zero viscosity" leads to "climb the walls". The key paragraph is this one:

> Superfluid helium's dual nature is at work again when it climbs the
> walls of a container. (Watch this YouTube video of the effect.) Any
> liquid will coat the sides of a dish in which it sits—thanks again to
> the slight attraction between atoms—but the liquid's internal friction
> limits how far the coating may spread. In superfluid helium, the
> frictionless film slithers over the whole container, creating a sort
> of arena through which the superfluid can flow. If the liquid has
> somewhere to fall after it climbs out of the dish, it will drip from
> the bottom of the container until it siphons out all the superfluid
> pooled above it.

Helium isn't so much flowing "against gravity" as "wetting the surface". Normally with water or other familiar liquids, there's a meniscus formed as the liquid is attracted to the atoms of the container. Viscosity and atom-atom attractions normally mean that as a few atoms of the fluid are attracted to the container, they drag the rest of the fluid along with them: The fluid layer doesn't want to get *too* thin, because the atoms are trying to stick together.

But in a superfluid like He (technically only some isotopes of He, plus a few other things), there's no atom-atom attraction. (Okay, there are probably some mutually-induced dipole interactions and generic quantum weirdness - physics gets weird if you take "zero" too seriously, but work with me here.) Thus a layer of the liquid can leak into pores thinner than it would normally be able to enter: nanometer-scale cracks rather than micron-scale, and the parts which are attracted to the surface of the container aren't responsible for dragging up the majority of the mass. What you get instead is approximately an atomic monolayer climbing the walls of the container due to fluid-surface attraction, with each atom responsible for only its own weight. (As an aside, I'm guessing intermolecular forces F are probably on the order of an eV/nm = 10^9 eV/m, masses m are on the order of a GeV/c^2 = 10^9 eV/c^2 = 10^-8 s^2 eV/m^2, and Earth's gravity g is about 10 m/s^2. By unit analysis, I'd expect gravity to suppress superfluid wetting where the gravitational force exceeds the wetting force, i.e. mg > F, or g > F/m = 10^17 m/s^2.... which you're probably not finding outside a black hole...  Also note that 10^17 atoms isn't much on a macroscopic scale, so this estimate is at least vaguely consistent with capillary action and observed meniscus.  I could well be off by a couple orders of magnitude in either direction - but it doesn't change the overall argument.)

Anyhow, a few atoms stick to the surface and go sliding along it till the container's covered in a monolayer. (Again, it doesn't have to be a literal monolayer. If there are a few layers of atoms due to "negligible" interatomic forces between the He atoms, we end up with the same macroscopic result.) Since it's a superfluid, where one atom goes, they can all go... so pretty soon you've got individual atoms exploring the whole of the surface - both inside and outside. The atoms flow toward the area on the surface with the lowest potential energy, i.e. the bottom of the outside of the container. Some of them stick to the container, but they can't *all* be in contact, so the overall flow is to have a monolayer fully covering the container with the majority of the mass at that lowest point. As more atoms spend time adhering to the bottom of the container, a drop forms and now you've got atoms jostling to be in it. Eventually the layer underneath the container becomes thick enough that some atoms don't feel much adhesion to the container - and they fall off.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important ingredients: 1) Wetting and 2) zero viscosity.

Wetting is not specific to the superfluid, and it allows a thin fluid layer to form on the surface of the container.

If the container is of finite height, you effectively get a U-shaped channel that connects the inside and the outside of the fluid. Can this lead to fluid flow? The fluid velocity on the surface is zero (this is the so-called no-slip condition), and a fluid flow requires strong shear strain (that is the fluid velocity changes rapidly as you go away from the surface). The force of friction is proportional to shear strain multiplied by viscosity. In a normal fluid this is too large to allow fluid flow (and indeed too large to allow significant spreading of the surface layer), but in the superfluid viscoity is zero, and the fluid can flow through the narrow surface channel.

Answer (score -1):

Liquid Helium as He-IV and He-III behave in this manner. The property of a material to have zero viscosity is known as superfluidity. This is only possible at cryogenic temperatures at the nano-kelvin level.

You may know viscosity as a measure of the 'thickness' of the fluid or a measure of how easily it can flow. When the viscosity drops to zero, there are no shear forces within the liquid and the liquid will try to spread out as much as possible. This will continue till the till the film becomes one molecule thick. The specifics of why this happens is explained by the Bose-Einstein Condensate statistics.

Comment: As noted in other answers to this question it is not a Bose-Einstein condensate. And how does this explanation explain it climbing walls?

Comment: @AndersSandberg      It is good to see a link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/lhel.html#:~:targetText=When%20helium%20is%20cooled%20to,a%20zero%20viscosity%20%22superfluid%22. supporting the statements. Other answers are just speculations on the lines of the miniscus of fluids. For viscosity . see this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pfric.html#vis for definition of viscosity